# Append specific caracter at the end of each line

Tags: sed, escaping, substitution, string-substitution

I have a file and I want to append a specific text, `\0A`, to the end of each of its lines.

I used this command,

```sh
sed -i s/$/\0A/ file.txt
```

but that didn't work with backslash `\0A`.

Comment: `sed -i 's/$/\\0A/' file.txt` ?

Comment: No that add just A

Comment: also note that you are not using quotes around `s/$/\0A/`, so the backslash will be interpreted by the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be fixed by simply enclosing `s/$/\0A/` in single quotes (`'`) ***and*** escaping the backslash (with another backslash):

```sh
sed -i 's/$/\\0A/' file.txt
```

Notice that the surrounding `'`s protect that string from being processed ***by the shell***, but the bashslash still needed escape in order to protect it ***from SED*** itself.

Obviously, it's still possible to avoid the single quotes if you escape enough:

```sh
sed -i s/$/\\\\0A/ file.txt
```

In this case there are no single quotes to protect the string, so we need write `\\` in the shell to get SED fed with `\`, but we need two  of those `\\`, i.e. `\\\\`, so that SED is fed with `\\`, which is an escaped `\`.

Move obviously, I'd never ever suggest the second alternative.

Answer (score 2):

In its default operations, `sed` cyclically appends a line from input, less it's terminating <newline>-character, into the pattern space of sed.

The OP wants to use `sed` to append the character `\0A` at the end of a line. This is the hexadecimal representation of the <newline>-character (cfr. http://www.asciitable.com/). So from this perspective, the  OP attempts to double space a files. This can be easilly done using:

```
sed G file
```

The `G` command, appends a newline followed by the content of the hold space to the pattern space. Since the hold space is always empty, it just appends a newline character to the pattern space. The default action of `sed` is to print the line. So this just double-spaces a file.